# Audio related programs inexplicably segfaulting after reading from urandom

Tags: audio, segmentation-fault, debian-jessie

I've been running debian as my main driver os for a few months now, and I've just started having a strange bug with some audio related applications.

A system call trace revealed this.

```
  ...
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
  ...
read(3, "~e\f9\224S\0160q\312Iz\341c9\306\300j\303\311\372)\331\301\16\304K\32\235\347\2659", 32) = 32
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x10} ---
```

(Full trace available [here](http://pastebin.com/gGjLuCRY))

The same thing occurs with several other programs, including vlc, rhythmbox, and idjc. Up until just a few days ago everything was working fine, so does anyone have any idea what could be going on here?

EDIT: Up until this time, all programs doing this were linked by the fact that they play audio, but it turns out that `wget` is also doing it. I should also add that I tried to replicate the bug with a `dd` line, but couldn't get `dd` to crash.

Interestingly, I've compared two trace logs, and the last 9 lines of them are identical, with the exception of the returned data from `read` and `getrusage`.

I've all but determined this is a problem with the GNUTLS library, but have yet to come up with a fix

Comment: Not a proper answer but a dirty fix that may be acceptable in some circumstances. Deleting `/dev/urandom` will avoid the `SEGV` and some
programs seem to survive it. The problem seems to be in reading `/dev/urandom`, not necessarily in
connection to audio. I got the same issue while trying to run `conky`. Everything started after a seemingly innocent upgrade at my debian box.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that the problem was in GNUTLS. I updated a few packages to the testing branch of debian, and my problems vanished.